# Questions tagged [Minecraft] and [Minecraft-xbox]

Tags: discussion, tags, minecraft

I asked [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/72441/using-the-map-item-on-minecraft-xbox-360), which is primarily focused on issues specific to the XBox 360 version of minecraft, but some of it is still of more general use to all minecraft users (map scale, map coloring scheme, etc.).

I originally tagged it with both [minecraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft) and [minecraft-xbox](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-xbox), but the [minecraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft) tag keeps getting removed.

I think it's clear that [minecraft-xbox] is appropriate for questions that are specific to the xbox version of the game (as a clarifier), but here are a few reasons I think the [minecraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft) tag should also stay:

1. All other questions tagged with [Minecraft-xbox] also have the [Minecraft] tag (or at least they did, before several others were similarly removed).
2. [minecraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft) is a much more popular tag (1269 vs 7), so will give the [minecraft-xbox](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-xbox) questions better visibility when searching. Removing the more popular tag bascially "orphans" these questions.
3. Several of the [minecraft-xbox](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-xbox) questions are asking about a problem that *ended up* being a bug or limitation specific to the XBox version. This is only apparent in retrospect, and isn't necessarily obvious to the asker of the original question, or to future searchers. The [minecraft] tag should stay to aid those future searchers who don't know this will end up being an issue specific to only one platform.

Is there a general policy regarding [game](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game) vs [game-platform](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-platform) tags?

Comment: Why not just tag it `[minecraft]` and `[xbox-360]`? It's a minecraft question, that is specific to the xbox

Comment: Seems reasonble, @Rachel. So the [minecraft-xbox] tag shouldn't even exist? Is that a method we've used in other cases?

Comment: I'm no expert on Gaming.SE, however yes I think that is the case based on the answer posted [here](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/4639/8462)

Comment: @rachel what you've proposed is the exact *opposite* of what I'm recommending in the post you linked. I would instead argue that [tag:minecraft-xbox] is the valid way to do things.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz Hrrm I actually didn't read the final paragraph when posting that :) I just read the main body and thought that sounded like this kind of situation

Comment: I think it's reasonable to tag it `[minecraft]` and `[minecraft-xbox]`, for a similar reason to tag a question `[diablo-3]` and `[diablo-3-monk]`: The question may be of interest to people browsing/searching either tag.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The great Minecraft tag family cleanup!](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14846/the-great-minecraft-tag-family-cleanup)

Answer (score 8):

To get it out of the way upfront, [minecraft-xbox](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-xbox) *isn't* of the format [game-platform](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-platform): the game in question is *Minecraft: Xbox 360 Edition*. Due to a number of reasons, it diverges quite heavily from the PC Minecraft, and *should* be considered a different game.

Think the difference between a game like, say *Call of Duty* and *Call of Duty: Modern Warfare*, or *Command & Conquer* and *Command & Conquer: Red Alert*: similar gameplay, same franchise, different games.

So the existence of [minecraft-xbox](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-xbox) does not justify something like [skyrim-xbox](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/skyrim-xbox), as both *Skyrim* for PC and *Skyrim* for Xbox 360 are the exact same game.

But it's really about whether [minecraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft) is appropriate on [minecraft-xbox](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-xbox) questions.

The weakest argument for the inclusion of both tags is:

> People who are interested in *Minecraft* are also necessarily interested in *Minecraft: Xbox 360 Edition* questions, so it should be tagged with both.

Which you presented as:

> [Minecraft] is a much more popular tag (1269 vs 7), so will give the [Minecraft-xbox] questions better visibility when searching. Removing the more popular tag bascially "orphans" these questions.

Even if this were remotely true, this isn't how tags work on Stack Exchange: we tag questions based on what they *are about*, not based on what the asker thinks will attract the largest audience. If we did that, every question would be tagged [skyrim](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/skyrim) or [diablo-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diablo-3).

Instead, the "official" workflow for people who *are* interested in all things *Minecraft* is to create a tag wildcard in their interesting tags: something like `[minecraft*]`.

Then, there's the second argument you presented, which was:

> Several of the [Minecraft-xbox] questions are asking about a problem that ended up being a bug or limitation specific to the XBox version. This is only apparent in retrospect, and isn't necessarily obvious to the asker of the original question, or to future searchers. The [minecraft] tag should stay to aid those future searchers who don't know this will end up being an issue specific to only one platform.

I'm not sympathetic to the "but the asker doesn't know beforehand" argument at all: Stack Exchange is designed to handle situations where the asker doesn't know everything about their situation. For one, the community can easily revise a post to ensure the asker is using the correct tags.

Secondly, the hyphens in tags are ignored in search engines: if a question was tagged incorrectly as [minecraft-xbox](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-xbox) when it's really talking about the original version *Minecraft*, it will still show up in search results for "minecraft" because search engines don't see "minecraft-xbox" as one word: they see "minecraft xbox".

Finally, the games have two different code bases and are about 1.5 years apart in terms of features. It's *exceedingly* unlikely a person will misidentify a question—much less a bug—about original Minecraft mechanics as being Xbox 360-only. An asker asking about a bug when they're playing *Minecraft: Xbox 360 Edition* is almost certainly not going to go wrong by tagging their question [minecraft-xbox](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-xbox).

The only related issue we'd have to worry about are people mis-tagging *Minecraft: Xbox 360 Edition* questions as simply [minecraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft), but again, that's why we have community editing.

Another argument is:

> Because there are so many versions of *Minecraft* out there now, [minecraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft) should be used as a synonym for [minecraft-series](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-series). [minecraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft)/[minecraft-series](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-series) should only be used if the question is about the game series, or about something that applies to all *Minecraft* editions.

I'm sympathetic to this argument, but there are a number of practical issues that need to be resolved:

- What happens to the hundreds of questions that are, in fact, about the PC Minecraft? Should they get renamed to [minecraft-pc](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-pc) or [minecraft-original-recipe](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-original-recipe)?
- How do we deal with the fact that people have been misusing the [minecraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft) tag for all the Minecraft games, which would prevent a simple rename?
- Furthermore, how to do we discourage people from just using [minecraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft)?
- What questions count as [minecraft-series](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-series) questions? Given how divergent all the editions of Minecraft are and how quickly the game iterates, what could reasonably be considered general enough to apply to all Minecraft editions?

Tha't not to say these questions are unresolvable, but  deserve a lot more discussion than a passing mention in the comments.

I think in the long term, it *might* make sense to disambiguate the [minecraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft) tag into [minecraft-series](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-series) and the edition tags, but for now:

- Use [minecraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft) if your question applies to the original version of *Minecraft*.
- Use [minecraft-xbox](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-xbox) if your question applies to *Minecraft: Xbox 360 Edition*.
- Use both tags if your question applies to both games (should be rare).