# The great Minecraft tag family cleanup!

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request, minecraft

It was [discussed recently](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/14800/171580) that the [minecraft](/questions/tagged/minecraft) tag family is potentially up to 6 years behind the actual reality of Minecraft naming conventions and versioning, and a lot of Minecraft tags are used incorrectly all the time, not only because they are so outdated.

I am trying to fix multiple of these problems with this proposal, which I had previously suggested in [this post](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14812/171580). Since my suggestion seems to have gotten only positive feedback (more upvotes than the question in the same time, no downvotes, only one minor change suggested in the comments, which I implemented here), I'll summarise my proposed changes here and proceed with executing the ones I can do myself after a few weeks, if nobody objects (hopefully with the help of others and hopefully a moderator does the tag merges and synonym deletions).

Since I don't want to create another [13K character monster post](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14812/171580), here is the short list of changes and arguments for the most important ones. Please see the earlier post for full descriptions/arguments:

---

## TO BE COMPLETED

This is a list of tasks that are yet to be completed:

- **Full review of tag wikis** - We need to check that all tag descriptions and wikis are up to date (especially not MCJava related ones)
- **Tag wiki edits** - for any identified above as being out of date (Please keep the following meta post in mind: [How should I write tag wikis?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7837/171580))

---

## COMPLETED

These are things that have been completed already. See the linked posts for a full breakdown of tasks.

- **Tag renames** - including merging and creating synonyms. [More Info](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14860/28182)
- **New Tag creation** - for relevant topic areas. [More Info](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14900/28182)
- **Tag deletion** - for tags that aren't needed. [More Info](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14900/28182)
- **Retagging questions** with more appropriate tags. [More Info](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14900/28182)
- **Removing synonyms** - old Minecraft terms that are no longer used. [More Info](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14900/28182)
- **Blacklisting [minecraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft) and [minecraft-console](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-console)** - these tag were replaced with version-specific tags as part of this cleanup, but were being constantly recreated. [More Info](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/14952/28182)

---

**Note: Please do not edit the tags of this question, they are all mandatory as per their usage guidelines.**

Comment: I've created [a chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103481/discussion-on-question-by-fabian-roling-the-great-minecraft-tag-family-cleanup) for handling and discussing this tag clean up.

Comment: Anything about minecraft story mode?

Comment: @Corsaka I didn't list anything here that can stay as it is. You can find all of those and reasons for all the changes here in [my older, super long post](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14812/171580).

Comment: @FabianRöling Why apply the change to Minecraft-mcedit? It is the only tag on this list that no longer conforms to having the "minecraft" prefix

Comment: Because it is not Minecraft, it is not made by Mojang and it does not contain "Minecraft" in its official name. It's only Minecraft **related**, but for example Amidst is also Minecraft related and, if it had a tag, should not contain "minecraft" in its tag name, for the same reasons.

Comment: About the tags of this question: All of them are required, so please do not remove any of them, not even to add [meta-tag:minecraft]. The [tag synonym and merging guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70718/353011) lists [meta-tag:discussion], [meta-tag:tags] and [meta-tag:synonym-request] as mandatory for tag synonym requests and [meta-tag:discussion], [meta-tag:tags] and [meta-tag:retag-request] as mandatory for tag merge requests (and there are multiple of both included in this post). Finally, [meta-tag:featured] is of course required for this post to be featured in the sidebar.

Comment: I have just created an excerpt/wiki for [tag:minecraft-bedrock-edition-realms], which I believe was the last minecraft tag without a wiki or excerpt? Might be a good time to kick off the review process for the tags themselves

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## COMPLETED

### Community actions

These actions were taken by the community:

#### Tag creation

- [minecraft-bedrock-edition-server](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-bedrock-edition-server)
- [minecraft-bedrock-edition-realms](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-bedrock-edition-realms)

#### Manual retagging

- some [minecraft-legacy-console](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-legacy-console) questions (new name) to [minecraft-bedrock-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-bedrock-edition)
- some [minecraft-java-edition-server](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-java-edition-server) questions (new name) to [minecraft-bedrock-edition-server](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-bedrock-edition-server)
- some [minecraft-java-edition-realms](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-java-edition-realms) questions (new name) to [minecraft-bedrock-edition-realms](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-bedrock-edition-realms)

#### Manual tag deletion

Achieved by removing them from questions. Full burnination procedure not required according to [the burnination guide](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/324071/6743127)).

- [minecraft-useful-pets](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-useful-pets)
- [minecraft-pocket-mine](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-pocket-mine)
- [minecraft-westeroscraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-westeroscraft)
- [minecraft-bigdig](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-bigdig)

#### Tag wiki edits

The following tags have been edited

- [minecraft-java-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-java-edition) (new name)

  - Added section for developer and release versions + updated to conform to our Tag Wiki Guidelines (Robotnik)
  - Added summaries on many different elements, playstyles and communities: redstone, PVP, decoration, teaching, commands, mods, roleplaying, bugs, hardcore, documentation, … (Fabian Röling)
- [minecraft-thermal-expansion](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-thermal-expansion) (new name)
- [minecraft-technic-pack](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-technic-pack)
- [minecraft-resource-packs](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-resource-packs)
- [minecraft-classic-browser](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-classic-browser) (new name)
- [minecraft-datapack](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-datapack)
- [minecraft-launcher](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-launcher)
- [minecraft-shader](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-shader)

---

### Moderator actions

#### Merges/renames

- [minecraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft)→[minecraft-java-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-java-edition)
- [minecraft-console](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-console)→[minecraft-legacy-console](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-legacy-console)
- [minecraft-pocket-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-pocket-edition), [minecraft-windows-10](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-windows-10)→[minecraft-bedrock-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-bedrock-edition)
- [minecraft-server](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-server)→[minecraft-java-edition-server](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-java-edition-server)
- [minecraft-realms](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-realms)→[minecraft-java-edition-realms](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-java-edition-realms)
- [minecraft-mcedit](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-mcedit)→[mcedit](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mcedit)
- [mc-equivalent-exchange](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mc-equivalent-exchange)→[minecraft-equivalent-exchange](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-equivalent-exchange)
- [minecraft-classic](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-classic)→[minecraft-classic-browser](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-classic-browser)
- [minecraft-pi-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-pi-edition)→[minecraft-raspberry-pi-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-raspberry-pi-edition) (undone because "Pi edition" is the official name, [minecraft-raspberry-pi-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-raspberry-pi-edition) is now a synonym)
- [minecraft-te](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-te)→[minecraft-thermal-expansion](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-thermal-expansion)
- [minecraft-seus](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-seus)→[minecraft-shader](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-shader)
- [minecraft-enderio](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-enderio), [minecraft-twilight-forest](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-twilight-forest), [minecraft-portal-gun](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-portal-gun), [minecraft-useful-pets](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-useful-pets) and [minecraft-biomes-o-plenty](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-biomes-o-plenty)→[minecraft-mods](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-mods)
- [minecraft-datapack](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-datapack)→[minecraft-data-packs](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-data-packs)

#### Tag Deletion

The following tags no longer exist after this process, because they were constantly misused. Not having these tags forces askers to select a more specific tag.

- [minecraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft)
- [minecraft-console](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-console)

#### Synonym creation

- [minecraft-pocket-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-pocket-edition), [minecraft-better-together](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-better-together), [minecraft-ios](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-ios), [minecraft-android](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-android), [minecraft-xbox-one](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-xbox-one), [minecraft-nintendo-switch](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-nintendo-switch), [minecraft-playstation-4](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-playstation-4), [minecraft-gear-vr](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-gear-vr) and [minecraft-fire-os](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-fire-os) for [minecraft-bedrock-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-bedrock-edition)

#### Synonym deletion

- [minecraft-beta](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-beta)
- [minecraft-smp](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-smp)
- [minecraft-nether](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-nether)
- [smp](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/smp)
- [minecraft-realms](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-realms)
- [minecraft-console](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-console)
- [minecraft-windows-10](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-windows-10)
- [minecraft-classic](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-classic)

#### Rescuing information from deleted tag wikis

- [minecraft-windows-10](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-windows-10)
- [minecraft-pocket-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-pocket-edition)

I took all the relevant information from the deleted tag wikis and turned it into tasks in this list. The full wordings are [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/53373144#53373144).

Comment: RE: your edit: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/revisions/363001/2

Answer (score 10):

The following merges/renames have been completed:

#### Merged/renamed without synonyms:

- [minecraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft)→[minecraft-java-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-java-edition)
- [minecraft-console](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-console)→[minecraft-legacy-console](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-legacy-console)
- [minecraft-windows-10](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-windows-10)→[minecraft-bedrock-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-bedrock-edition)
- [minecraft-realms](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-realms)→[minecraft-java-edition-realms](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-java-edition-realms)
- [minecraft-classic](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-classic)→[minecraft-classic-browser](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-classic-browser)
- [minecraft-server](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-server)→[minecraft-java-edition-server](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-java-edition-server)
- [minecraft-datapack](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-datapack)→[minecraft-data-packs](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-data-packs)

#### Merged/renamed with synonyms:

- [minecraft-pocket-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-pocket-edition)→[minecraft-bedrock-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-bedrock-edition)
- [minecraft-mcedit](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-mcedit)→[mcedit](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mcedit)
- [mc-equivalent-exchange](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mc-equivalent-exchange)→[minecraft-equivalent-exchange](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-equivalent-exchange)
- [minecraft-pi-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-pi-edition)→[minecraft-raspberry-pi-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-raspberry-pi-edition) (undone because "Pi edition" is the official name, [minecraft-raspberry-pi-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-raspberry-pi-edition) is now a synonym)
- [minecraft-te](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-te)→[minecraft-thermal-expansion](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-thermal-expansion)
- [minecraft-seus](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-seus)→[minecraft-shader](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-shader)
- [minecraft-enderio](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-enderio), [minecraft-twilight-forest](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-twilight-forest), [minecraft-portal-gun](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-portal-gun), [minecraft-useful-pets](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-useful-pets) and [minecraft-biomes-o-plenty](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-biomes-o-plenty)→[minecraft-mods](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-mods)

#### Other related synonym changes

- Deleted [minecraft-xbox](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-xbox)→[minecraft-legacy-console](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-legacy-console)
- Added [minecraft-xbox-360](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-xbox-360)→[minecraft-legacy-console](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-legacy-console)
- Added several platform related synonyms for [minecraft-bedrock-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-bedrock-edition) such as [minecraft-ps4](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-ps4) and [minecraft-xbox-one](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-xbox-one)

If there are any more tag wikis that got messed up in this process, let me know and I'll try and find them.

Comment: [tag:minecraft-classic] should NOT be a synonym, because it is ambiguous between the new one played in browsers and the old version naming scheme of Minecraft Java edition. Please delete this synonym. What about the tag wikis of [tag:minecraft-pocket-edition] and [tag:minecraft-windows-10], did you copy their contents somewhere or merge the information of them into [tag:minecraft-bedrock-edition]?

Comment: @FabianRöling I actually didn't realize that Classic now runs in a browser now, so I'll take another look and probably remove it. I also did look at the pocket edition and windows 10 wikis and there's not a lot of relevant content there to begin with, but I'll take another look at that later today to make sure I'm not missing anything. (I might just rewrite the wiki from scratch)