# Improve Resident Evil's tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-rename-request, retag-request

Recently I posted a question about the *Resident Evil 1 Remake*, but I got a bit confused about which tag to use. Initially I've used [resident-evil](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resident-evil), but later I realize that I should use [resident-evil-2002](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resident-evil-2002) instead.

And, out of curiosity, I took a look in *Resident Evil's* tags and I realized **how confusing they are**.

###### Resident Evil 1:

We have [resident-evil](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resident-evil) for the original game from 1996, and [resident-evil-2002](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resident-evil-2002) for the remake.

###### Resident Evil 2:

We have [resident-evil-2-1998](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resident-evil-2-1998) for the original game from 1998, and [resident-evil-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resident-evil-2) for the remake, **the opposite nomenclature of the first game**.

###### Resident Evil 3:

We have [resident-evil-nemesis](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resident-evil-nemesis) for the original game from 1999, and [resident-evil-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resident-evil-3) for the remake, now **neither of the two tags has the year in it**.

###### Resident Evil 4:

We have [resident-evil-4](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resident-evil-4) for the original game from 2005, and [resident-evil-4-remake](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resident-evil-4-remake) **for the remake**.

Every game that had a remake has its own pattern for the tags, which makes all of them confusing. In  [*Do we need Resident Evil 2 - Remake tag?*](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13251/306358), [Wipqozn](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/users/8350/wipqozn) said:

> I highly doubt we're going to suddenly find ourselves overrun with questions for the original, so might as well use the shorter tag for the more recent game.

And I totally agree, my suggestion is to follow *Resident Evil 2* pattern and rename the tags this way:

- [resident-evil-1996](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resident-evil-1996) for the original, and [resident-evil](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resident-evil) for the remake
- *Resident Evil 2* tags don't change
- [resident-evil-3-1999](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resident-evil-3-1999) for the original, and [resident-evil-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resident-evil-3) for the remake
- [resident-evil-4-2005](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resident-evil-4-2005) for the original, and [resident-evil-4](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resident-evil-4) for the remake

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree, this is a bit of a mess. Normally we prefer to just add the year of release to the newest release/version of the game, but I agree with galacticninja that this would be a case where having the year of release across all tags would make it a lot clearer moving forward.

I've gone ahead and made these changes, similar to what [galacticninja proposed](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16909/28182) but with extra synonyms for the remake versions as well:

| Main tag | Synonyms | Tag Wiki |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [resident-evil-1996](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resident-evil-1996) | [resident-evil](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resident-evil) | Yes |
| [resident-evil-2-1998](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resident-evil-2-1998) | [resident-evil-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resident-evil-2) | Yes |
| [resident-evil-3-nemesis](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resident-evil-3-nemesis) | [resident-evil-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resident-evil-3), [resident-evil-nemesis](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resident-evil-nemesis) | No |
| [resident-evil-4-2005](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resident-evil-4-2005) | [resident-evil-4](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resident-evil-4) | Yes |
| [resident-evil-2002](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resident-evil-2002) | [resident-evil-remake](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resident-evil-remake), [resident-evil-2015-remaster](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resident-evil-2015-remaster), [resident-evil-hd-remaster](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resident-evil-hd-remaster) | Yes |
| [resident-evil-2-2019](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resident-evil-2-2019) | [resident-evil-2-remake](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resident-evil-2-remake) | Yes |
| [resident-evil-3-2020](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resident-evil-3-2020) | [resident-evil-3-remake](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resident-evil-3-remake) | No |
| [resident-evil-4-2023](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resident-evil-4-2023) | [resident-evil-4-remake](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resident-evil-4-remake) | No |

This should help to disambiguate the tags and make it easier on everyone to find what they're looking for. If anyone wants to add some tag excerpts/wikis for the tags that lack them, please do! :)

Comment: I agree with these changes. Appending “remake” to the tag synonyms makes sense too.

Comment: I noticed that most of the questions currently tagged with [[tag:resident-evil-1996]] are actually about the 2015 Resident Evil HD Remaster, which is a remaster of the 2002 remake. To avoid confusion, I think we should add some tag synonyms for the 2015 remaster pointing to [[tag:resident-evil-2002]] as well. I have updated the tag usage guidance for the 1996 game tag accordingly and will be correcting the tags for the affected questions.

Comment: Thanks @galacticninja. I've updated the above synonyms for RE 2002 to include references to the 2015 HD remaster. :)

Comment: Perfect, what an improvement! But, how about using [tag:resident-evil-3-1999] as the main tag and [tag:resident-evil-3-nemesis] as a synonym?

Comment: @DiegoBorba - I went back and forth on adding `1999` to the RE 3 Nemesis tag. In the end I agreed with galacticninja's reasoning, the remake dropped the extra 'nemesis' term thus the game and it's remake had different enough names that it could stand without the year being appended (which is what we generally prefer).

Answer (score 4):

As discussed in the previous meta posts, [“How to handle multiple games with the same exact name?”](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5473/4797) (2012) and [“Are we making new tags for duplicate game names hard(er) to use?”](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11584/4797) (2016), the community consensus is that the tag for a newer game that shares its name with an older game should have the year of release appended.

The top-voted answers on these posts differ on whether the older game’s tag should also have a year appended. I prefer the tagging policy suggested by the older meta post, which is to append the year to both games’ tags.

This way, there is no confusion about which tag should be used for which game, even without looking at the tag wikis. Also, we wouldn’t need to retag if the game gets remade again in the future.

For example, [resident-evil-1996](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resident-evil-1996) (original) and [resident-evil-2002](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resident-evil-2002) (remake). And if it gets remade again in 2024 and is still named *Resident Evil*, the tag for that game would be [resident-evil-2024](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resident-evil-2024).

Note that the 2002 remake was remastered in 2015 — *Resident Evil HD Remaster*. On some services, such as Steam, this version of the game is listed as "*Resident Evil*", with no "*HD Remaster*". To avoid further confusion about this, we should add tag synonyms pointing the 2015 remaster to the 2002 remake.

We should use the official spelling of the game name in the tags whenever possible, so the tag for the 1999 game should be [resident-evil-3-nemesis](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resident-evil-3-nemesis) to reflect the game's official name, *Resident Evil 3: Nemesis*. I feel that the "1999" year suffix is not necessary here since the 2020 remake is named "*Resident Evil 3*", with no "Nemesis".

As per the above, here are my suggestions:

| Original | Synonym* to original | Remake | Synonym to remake |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [resident-evil-1996](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resident-evil-1996) | [resident-evil](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resident-evil) | [resident-evil-2002](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resident-evil-2002) | [resident-evil-remake](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resident-evil-remake) [resident-evil-2015](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resident-evil-2015) [resident-evil-hd-remaster](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resident-evil-hd-remaster) |
| [resident-evil-2-1998](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resident-evil-2-1998) | [resident-evil-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resident-evil-2) | [resident-evil-2-2019](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resident-evil-2-2019) | [resident-evil-2-remake](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resident-evil-2-remake) |
| [resident-evil-3-nemesis](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resident-evil-3-nemesis) | [resident-evil-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resident-evil-3) [resident-evil-nemesis](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resident-evil-nemesis) | [resident-evil-3-2020](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resident-evil-3-2020) | [resident-evil-3-remake](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resident-evil-3-remake) |
| [resident-evil-4-2005](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resident-evil-4-2005) | [resident-evil-4](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resident-evil-4) | [resident-evil-4-2023](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resident-evil-4-2023) | [resident-evil-4-remake](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resident-evil-4-remake) |

* As [arghtype suggested in the comments](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16908/improve-resident-evils-tags/16909?noredirect=1#comment49520_16909), we could make [resident-evil](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resident-evil) a synonym for [resident-evil-1996](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resident-evil-1996). I think blacklisting it (and showing appropriate tag usage guidance) would be better so that the user will be required to specify which game they're referring to, as is the case for [minecraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft): "[Should we add [minecraft] to the tag blacklist?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/14952/4797)".

The community managers will have to implement this change, which might take some time. Until then, we should follow arghtype’s advice and make [resident-evil](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resident-evil) a synonym of [resident-evil-1996](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resident-evil-1996); the same thing with the sequels.

Comment: How about also adding synonyms to point to original games, like `resident-evil` -> `resident-evil-1996` ?

Comment: also, what are we going to do when they finally release game #1996 in the series?

Comment: @arghtype That [[tag:resident-evil]] synonymization suggestion makes sense. I think blacklisting it (with a tag usage message) would be better so that the user will be required to specify which game they're referring to, as is the case for [[tag:minecraft]], but the CMs will have to make that change. I've raised this issue in my answer.

Comment: Yeah. Minecraft had several thousand questions, the need for blacklisting in that case was apparent, but given that the RE tags combined don't even hit 100 questions, I think renaming with synonyms is good enough.