# How should we tag questions about the 2023 and 1992 Mortal Kombat 1s?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-rename-request, tag-synonyms

A new *Mortal Kombat* game, confusingly titled "*Mortal Kombat 1*" (2023), is out. It sort of shares the same name as the first *Mortal Kombat* from 1992, which is also referred to as "Mortal Kombat 1".

How can we avoid confusion when tagging questions about these two games? Do we need any tag synonyms to help users find the right tag?

Related: [Improve Resident Evil's tags](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16908/4797)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the previous meta posts: “[How to handle multiple games with the same exact name?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5473/4797)” and “[Improve Resident Evil’s tags](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16908/4797)”, if two games share the same name, they both should have the year of release appended to their tags. This way, there is no confusion about which tag should be used for which game, even without looking at the tag wikis.

In line with the above, here are my suggestions:

| Game | Tag | Tag synonym |
| --- | --- | --- |
| *Mortal Kombat* (1992) | [mortal-kombat-1992](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mortal-kombat-1992) | [mortal-kombat](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mortal-kombat) |
| *Mortal Kombat 1* (2023) | [mortal-kombat-1-2023](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mortal-kombat-1-2023) | [mortal-kombat-1](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mortal-kombat-1) |

Comment: Made the changes described.  You can accept this when able to.